# Link an ID to a button

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, razor

My foreach loops all the people from the database (2 people), but when I click on the 'Wijzig' button it always shows the data from the first person. Is there a way to link it to the same row it's in?

This is my View, the first row is me and my details. The second one is a friend and his details.

[image]

When you click on the button 'Wijzig' it shows you a popup with this form below. I blurred the information out, but it shows my information on both the 'Wijzig' buttons. How can I link a button to the person in that row? Do I have to change something in my model or in my foreach loop?

[image]

My view (I think this is all the code you need):

```
 @if (Model.Bestuur.Bestuursleden.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var i in Model.Bestuur.Bestuursleden)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td width="100">
                                <div id="flip"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/finance-vol-2-2/128/finance-56-128.png" class="circular" width="100px" height="100px">
                            <td width="350px">
                                <label for="persoon" style="width: 400px;">@i.Persoon.Voornaam @i.Persoon.Achternaam</label><p>Email: @i.Persoon.Email <br>Woonplaats: @i.Persoon.Woonplaats<br>Telefoonnummer: @i.Persoon.Telnr)</p>

                                <div id = "panel" style = "display: none;" >
                                    Meer informatie: @i.Persoon.Informatie
                                </div>
                            </td>
            </div>


            <td>
                <label for= "persoon"> @i.Funktie.Naam </label>


             </td>


            <td style="border-color: transparent;">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalNorm" name="id" style="background-color: #42a5f5; border-color: #42a5f5; margin-left: 20px;">Wijzig</button>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I usually achieve this by using a button type and giving it a data attribute to store the Id. E.g

```
<button type="button" data-id="@i.Id.ToString()" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalNorm" name="id" style="background-color: #42a5f5; border-color: #42a5f5; margin-left: 20px;">Wijzig</button>
```

You then using jQuery to handle the button being clicked. Parse the ID using the .attr("data-id") method and call your server with ajax.

```
$('.btn-primary').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id=$(this).attr("data-id");

    //use ajax to query the data for this Id

    //Bind to form

    //Show modal
});
```

Once you've done that, you can bind to the modal form and show the modal.

Comment: Where do I put the jQuery? In my view? And what query do I use? SELECT FROM [Table] WHERE ID = @I.Persoon.Id? And what is binding a form?

Comment: You'll need to add a reference to jQuery itself, and then usually you'll have a Javascript file for each view or component. I usually have one per view. Reference that custom JS file below your reference to jQuery and then wrap my example JS above within jQuerys $(document).ready function. I presume you have a Controller Action which accepts the Id and returns the object?

Comment: I have a controller, but not an Action that accepts the Id and returns the object? Do you have TeamViewer? Chat? I am very confused because I am so lost

Comment: Sorry but I'm not going to have a team viewer call with you to explain the most basic of concepts in web development. Your question was how to link a button to an Id, and I've answered that. Once you have that Id in Javascript, you need to use it to call a new controller action that accepts the Id, and returns whatever you need it to. One of the easiest ways to do it is return a PartialView. This will be HTML which you can inject into the Modal Body.